# Can constructor Initializer fields be called with class objects, c++

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor, initializer-list

I have two classes, one "bank" and one "account". Account's constructor takes an int and a string. Bank is supposed to have two objects of type "account" in it. Is it possible to have the two "account" objects in the fields initializer list be allocated dynamically and not with static values?

Here is the code I have that allocates it statically

```
    class Bank
{
public:
    Bank():checkings( 500, "C"), saving( 300, "s"){} //predfined int and string

private:
    Account checkings;
    Account saving;

};
```

Is it possible to do this? I want the constuctor to have its fields allocated dynamically according to user input. I keep getting errors so I am unsure if my syntax is wrong.

```
    class Bank
{
public:
    Bank():checkings( int val, string s), saving( int val, string s){} //dynamic

private:
    Account checkings;
    Account saving;

};
```

Also, how do I call this type of constructor in the .cpp file?

Comment: `Bank():checkings( int val, string s), saving( int val, string s){}` is indeed a syntax error. To specify constructor parameters, they go between the first set of `()` on that line.

Answer (score 2):

You can't put declarations (like `int val`) in a member initializer, only expressions (which can be/include previously declared variables).

It looks like maybe you want:

```
class Bank
{
public:
    Bank(int val, std::string s) : checkings(val, s), saving(val, s) {}
    // ...
};
```

or:

```
class Bank
{
public:
    Bank(int check_val, std::string check_s,
         int sav_val, std::string sav_s) :
        checking(check_val, check_s), saving(sav_val, sav_s) {}
    // ...
};
```

Comment: If I do an initializer list like this does it become a definition instead of a declaration? Since when I try putting a definition in the .cpp file I get an error

Comment: A constructor definition always has `{}` and might have an initializer list.  A constructor declaration that is not a definition has neither, and has a `;` after the `)`.